# Merge multiple columns into 1 in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have a dataframe.

```
id    val    val2    val3
1      100    nan     nan
2      nan    200     nan
3      nan    nan     200
4      nan    500     nan
```

i want to merge columns `val,val2, and val3` into 1.
i.e
my final dataframe should look like:

```
id    val
1     100
2     200
3     200
4     500
```

Comment: What if more than 1 column on a given row has a value? If you only ever have a single value then you could just do `df.sum(axis=1)`

Comment: @EdChum Assumption is in a row only 1 out of 3 columns has value